# copyright management in IntelliJ is confusing

Tags: intellij-idea, copyright-display

I'm trying to understand the [IntelliJ copyright documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/copyright.html) and having trouble because I don't know whether it supports a feature that I'm accustomed to in emacs.

In the emacs mode I'm accustomed to, whenever I go to save a file using the copyright-minor-mode, the editor would take one of two actions

1. If the file was missing a copyright notice, emacs would ask me whether I wanted to insert one
2. If there was already a copyright notice, but the year was different, emacs would automatically append the current year to the year-list in the notice.

Is this model supported with the IntelliJ copyright approach?   As far as I can see, the user is required to remember to check and update the copyright notice.  But nothing prevents creating or saving files missing the notice or with the wrong year.

Granted, the IntelliJ seems to have a wonderful generalization which the emacs minor mode was missing, i.e., the ability to support several different types of copyright notices in the same project.

Also it is not clear to me whether the copyright philosophy is a personal choice or a project configuration.   I.e., if someone git-clones my project, I'd like his IntelliJ to treat copyrights the same was as I have established for the project/session/user.

Is my understanding correct?  Am I over-ambitious with my expectations?   How similar or different is the IntelliJ copyright philosophy to my expectation?

==========================

A bit of additional information.

Here is how I've filled out the Update Copyright dialog, yet clicking OK on this form does not seem to insert a copyright message into the scala file.
[image]

And here is how the Editor-Scala preferences are configured.
[image]

And here is the copyright profiles dialog.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

> If there was already a copyright notice, but the year was different, emacs would automatically append the current year to the year-list in the notice.
>   As far as I know, it should be done manually each time. Here's the relevant documentation: www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/copyright.html#update-copyright

Comment: Yes, I've seen the documentation, thanks for the link.  My OP is that after reading the documentation, many things are still unclear and confusing.